# JQuery Datepicker is not shown inside primefaces dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, datepicker

I want to use jquery datapicker for a textbox. In page it is getting displayed. But same thing i am using inside primefaces dialog, but datapicker is not getting displayed.

Here is my xhtml code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="../templates/ui.xhtml">

    <h:head>
    <title>Page title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/JqueryUICalender/jquery.datepick.css"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/JqueryUICalender/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/JqueryUICalender/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jq=jQuery.noConflict(true);
        jq(document).ready(function() 
        {

            jq("[id='form1id:dumid']").datepick({ 
                multiSelect: 999, monthsToShow: 1, 
                showTrigger: '#calImg'});

            jq("[id='form2id:calenderinputid']").datepick({ 
                multiSelect: 999, monthsToShow: 1, 
                showTrigger: '#calImg'});
        });
    </script>
    </h:head>
    <f:view>

    <h:body >

    <p:layout fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border:none">
        <h:form id="form1id">
            <table width="90%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p:inputText id="dumid"></p:inputText>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p:commandButton value="Open Dialog" onClick="PF('dialogwidgetwar').show()"/>
        </h:form>

         <p:dialog header="Header" id="dialogid" widgetVar="dialogwidgetwar" dynamic="true" closable="false" 
                resizable="false" draggable="false" width="400" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" position="450,80">

                <h:form id ="form2id">
                    <table width="90%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p:inputText id="calenderinputid" value=""/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
          </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
   </p:layoutUnit>


    </p:layout>
    </h:body>    
    </f:view>
    </html>
```

While i am clicking dumid text box, datapicker is being shown. But while clicking calendarinputid text box inside popup, datepicker is not being shown.

Comment: You can check in debug mode (of the browser) that if any error occurs on the seccond text box click. If some elementid etc is throwing some exception. (Developer mode F12)

Comment: @yeppe No error(exception) is shown in console of browser.